# How to know which texts are selected on UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift3

I have a list of texts(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', ...]). We can imagine that is tags belong to a book. I insert space character between these tags liked "aaa, bbb, ccc", then put the text to a UILabel. UILabel will automatically calculate height & width for me (I'm extremely like this)
Now once user clicks on a tag then app will navigate to an appropriate tag screen. But, how can I know which tag is selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a third party library [TTTattributedlabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) to detect tap on the label.

You can add link to each tag and detect tap on that tag from the delegate method `attributedLabel(_ label: TTTAttributedLabel!, didSelectLinkWith url: URL!)`